# I updated ghc to a new version, how do I automatically reinstall all cabal packages?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

For instance, I've just updated ghc from 7.6.2 to 7.6.3 and would like just reinstall all the packages I had previously installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running

```
cabal install world
```

will install all the previously installed packages. Some packages might not install, in which case one can delete them from ~/.cabal/world and run the command again, and install them again later when they are working again with that version of ghc.